# How to modify a Numpy 2D array in every row but specific column indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is what I am doing now to achieve what I want.

```
In: 
a=numpy.zeros((3,2))
a[range(a.shape[0]),[0,0,1]] = 1
a
Out:
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

As you can see, I used `range` function to select all the rows in a. Is there any other cleaner way to select every row?

Comment: *Cleaner* as in less characters?

Comment: no, I mean like built-in mechanism. For example when we use `:` without numbers around, it can select the whole dimension. I couldn't make it work here. Is there other operator for this purpose?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any.

Comment: This is the normal way of selecting these 3 items ( (0,0),(1,0) and (2,1) ).  It's pure simple `advanced` indexing, with 2 matching lists.

Answer (score 0):

Doing ***this specific thing*** can be done more cleanly, as you're just constructing a one-hot array, and there are [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592324/one-hot-encoding-using-numpy) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/numpy-1-hot-array) for "clean" ways to do this in `numpy`.  I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42874726/4427777) one by @MartinThoma:

```
a = np.eye(2)[[0,0,1]]
```

Also, most machine learning packages have their own one-hot encoding method that will be even more efficient and "clean" than this one, as machine learning is the most common use of one-hot encoding.

However, in general eliminating the `range` coordinate when doing this sort of fancy indexing is not possible.  There really isn't a clear, explicit way to represent that operation that wouldn't be confusing when you want to extend the representation beyond 2 dimensions.  And working in more than 2 dimensions at a time is the whole point of `numpy`