# Transform values of 1D numpy array to column numbers in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I require the following logic:

- The output array has the same amount of rows as the number of
  elements in the input array
- The values of the input array denote the column numbers of the output array (the number of columns equals the maximum number in the input array)
- The output array's values should be 1 if the input array contains the specific combination, 0 otherwise

For example, I'd like to transform a numpy array such as

```
[2, 1, 1, 0]
```

into an array that looks like this

```
[[0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0]]
```

The only thing I can come up with is filling an empty array with a for-loop. Any more "numpy-ish" way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  In particular, describe the logic that produces the given output from the given input.

Comment: how do to choose the number of columns? what you saif is not clear

Comment: @makis I edited to make it more clear

Comment: got it yes. see my answer

Comment: What do you mean by "specific combination"? Your example just looks like a one-hot encoding. If so, then this answer works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42874726/8793975

Comment: @enumaris Yea you are right, one-hot encoding works. I didn't know there is a name for this. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
before = [2, 1, 1, 0]

n_rows = len(before)
n_columns = max(before) + 1

output = np.zeros((n_rows, n_columns))

#loop constructor
for idx,i in enumerate(before): output[idx,i] = 1

array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: e.g., if the first element in the input array equals 2, the output array should be 1 at the first row in the third column (column index 2).

Comment: got it see my updated answer